# .Net webservice could not find my DLL-file

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, visual-studio, dllimport

I have a `.NET` `c#` web service.
In the implementation of this web service, I call a function of a my `.dll` library, which 
I am loading in the following way:

```
[DllImport("myLibrary.dll")]
extern static myMethod();
```

Where do I have to put my DLL? If I use this DLL in my test project (which is *not* a Web service project), it works.

Otherwise I have a error because it can not find the dll.

ERROR:

```
System.DllNotFoundException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Unable to load DLL 'myLibrary.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

Comment: Did you try to copy that to the bin directory where you deploy your web service? (To do not forget it you may even add it to your project selecting "Copy if newer" in the "Copy to output directory" in the properties of the file. Well...I don't like this but take it as an option).

Comment: Yes, I have tried to copy the dll into the directory

Comment: I copied into all subdirectory of myproject but not work..
I Solved in this way: I have put the path: C:\myLibrary.dll.. but..Why?

Answer (score 0):

That assembly needs to be in the same directory as the assembly that uses it. So, if the web service is deployed to IIS and its assembly resides in `bin` then the `myLibrary.dll` needs to be there too.

Comment: @GgSalent, is this an unmanaged assembly (e.g. an old C++ assembly)?

Comment: I did not understand.. :( my dll language is c++

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed "Visual C++ Redistributable für Visual Studio" on your Server?
If not this this could be the problem.